# Same integer lists, different byte arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

I have a question about interesting thing that happened to me when I have tried to convert elements of `List<short>` to `byte[]` in C#.

Firstly, I had to read large binary file, which contains 262144 `short` type `signed` numbers. I have read the file and build list of numbers with the following code:

```
byte[] content = null;
content = File.ReadAllBytes(scanName);
List<int> transformed = new List<int>();

for (int n = 0; n < content.Length; n += 2) // 2 bytes 
{
  short sample = BitConverter.ToInt16(content, n);
  transformed.Add(sample);
}
```

Then I have compressed and decompressed numbers with algorithm and got back same values, which seemed right. The problems occurs when try to convert both lists to byte arrays. This has been done by following method:

```
private byte[] ToByte(List<short> list){
    List<byte> toRet = new List<byte>();

    foreach(short s in list)
    {
       byte[] converted = BitConverter.GetBytes(s);
        foreach(byte b in converted)
        {
           toRet.Add(b);
        }
     }
    return toRet.ToArray();
}
```

But when I compared both byte arrays with `first.SequenceEqual(second)`, the method returned `false`. Isn't it strange, because values in both lists are same?

Comment: Are you sure of lists equality? How did u check that?

Comment: I have compare their values with for loop. @hessamhedieh

Comment: You are not reading from the list but from a shortArray on the seconde method. mistake not using list?

Comment: Could not reproduce the problem, maybe a full compiling code may help.

Comment: @Aldert Thank you, made a mistake during writing to StackOverflow. Thank you, the question is updated.

Comment: What I am confused about is that you use first a List<int > and later go to List<short> . You also convert to Int16 and then go with GetBytes. Might this be a case of unsigned versus signed?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I have solved the issue. The problem wasn't in converting short to byte, but in the part of code which hasn't been published there. Specifically, I made very beginner mistake, I converted 2D array into 1D array in the wrong way. Now everything works perfectly. Thank you for all your responses and sorry for inconveniences!